# Going back one directory without wanting

Tags: php, html, directory

I'm colaborating with another person and just got their code, when I try and run it nothing loads because all file names are going back one directory like `htdocs/dir/index.php` if i try in php `include_once('test.php')` it would error out because there is no file `htdocs/test.php`, I'm sorry for bad writing

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: You can try with `include_once( __DIR__ . 'test.php');`  if index.php and test.php is in same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using `./test.php` instead